# magento set drop down as readonly not working

Tags: magento

I need to set a drop down as readonly. I put it as;

```
<select readonly="readonly" name="name" >
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<select>
```

But this is not working. Since it is readonly, we can change the drop down value.

Please help.Thank You.

Comment: Some context of why you'd want to make a dropdown non-interact-able might help answerers to be out.

Comment: I am selecting the option value automatically. So i do not want customer to select it or change it. so i need to put it as readonly. I used disabled. But then the value is not saving after the form submission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `select` tag doesn't have a `readonly` attribute. It does have a `disabled`.

The problem with `disabled` is that form inputs don't get included in the POST / GET data.

To get around this, add another `hidden` input with the same name and value.

Comment: thank for helping. Yes with disabled this issue is there. I tried that also. Is there anyway of creating a hidden input like '" $select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')"

Comment: Without creating a hidden input like in above, i created a hidden input in template file and then in onload event i set the dropdown value into the hidden input. Then it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
<select>
  <option disabled="disabled">1</option>
  <option selected="selected">2</option>
</select>
```